# ArcPy TopoToRaster parameter settings

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, parameters, anudem

I'd like to create a script tool to create Topo DEM with TopoToRaster, but the parameters are not valid.
I tried using the help: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/topo-to-raster.htm and also "Copy as python snippet" funtion too.

However the parameters error get:

```
Traceback(mostrecentcalllast):File"D:\zites.py",line24,in<module>
topo_DEM=arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(in_topo_features="magassagm_fieldPointElevation",out_surface_raster="topo_DEM",cell_size="10",extent="buff45",Margin="20",minimum_z_value="",maximum_z_value="",enforce="ENFORCE",data_type="SPOT",maximum_iterations="20",roughness_penalty="",discrete_error_factor="1",vertical_standard_error="0",tolerance_1="2,5",tolerance_2="100",out_stream_features="",out_sink_features="",out_diagnostic_file="",out_parameter_file="",profile_penalty="",out_residual_feature="",out_stream_cliff_error_feature="",out_contour_error_feature="")
File"c:\programfiles(x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\ddd.py",line4515,inTopoToRaster
raisee
ExecuteError:ERROR 000622:Failed to execute(TopotoRaster).Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628:Cannot set input in t oparameter extent.
```

This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.ddd import *

racs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
magassag = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
m_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Sentinel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
topo_gdb = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput= True
buff45= "D:\\termes_modell.gdb\\buff45"

arcpy.env.workspace= topo_gdb
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(Sentinel)
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(racs, buff45, "45 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL", "", "PLANAR")
arcpy.AddMessage("buffer kesz")

arcpy.env.cellSize= Sentinel
arcpy.env.snapRaster = Sentinel
arcpy.env.extent= buff45
topo_DEM= arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(in_topo_features="magassag m_field PointElevation", out_surface_raster="topo_DEM", cell_size="10", extent="buff45", Margin="20", minimum_z_value="", maximum_z_value="", enforce="ENFORCE", data_type="SPOT", maximum_iterations="20", roughness_penalty="", discrete_error_factor="1", vertical_standard_error="0", tolerance_1="2,5", tolerance_2="100", out_stream_features="", out_sink_features="", out_diagnostic_file="", out_parameter_file="", profile_penalty="", out_residual_feature="", out_stream_cliff_error_feature="", out_contour_error_feature="")
arcpy.AddMessage("topoDEM kesz")
```

How can I use get parameters and environments here?

Comment: You should check out/in the 3d extension. May not be the issue but good practice.

Comment: When you got those error messages what parameter values did your tool dialog pass in?

Comment: `"buff45"` is a literal string and is not the same as `buff45` which is a variable that points to `"D:\\termes_modell.gdb\\buff45"`